# Replacing `jessie` with `stable` in raspbian `sources.list`?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, software-installation, update

in debian etc/apt/sources.list it is possible to replace the name of the current distribution with the `status` of a given distribution. For example, if one plans to use always the `stable` release can replace `jessie` with `stable` and the new release will be updated automagically when it comes up. Is the same possible with raspbian? I tried searching for a response and I was not successful and I prefer not too try just replacing the names since I have a working pi and like to keep it that way. Thank you!

Comment: Upgrading to a newer debian version is nothing you want to happen automatically. I happens less than once a year and requires some time and some care. Performing some `sudo sed -i 's/jessie/stretch/g' /etc/apt/sources.list` shouldn't hurt you if you want to keep your system working.